# Azure Service Bus over http behind proxy

Tags: servicebus, azureservicebus

Microsoft has released the new version of service bus 1.8 last week.  I am wondering wheter they have fixed the below issue disscussed in previous post.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/a7c78246-9d76-482a-b683-fc4a1e27df59

[Publish to Azure Service Bus over http behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281570/publish-to-azure-service-bus-over-http-behind-proxy/13116717#13116717)

I have tested on latest release and seems the issue is still exits.

Could not connect to net.tcp://abc.servicebus.windows.net:9354/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0500000. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 65.52.160.127:9354

Can anyone please guide me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the proxy address in the binding? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.webhttprelaybinding.proxyaddress.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have made improvements here with SDK 1.8, specifically for older proxies. Please set the `ConnectivityMode` to `AutoDetect` for ServiceBus client and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting ConnectivityMode to Http and specifying the proxy I want to use in app.config. It is a global state for the application, but it worked for my scenarios so maybe it is helpful here also. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

In my scenario the configuration was to ignore the proxy:

```
 <system.net>
   <defaultProxy>
     <proxy usesystemdefault="False" />
   </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```